# Walks of Even Length on a Bipartite Graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, symmetry

Given a random walk on a simple $d$-regular bipartite graph $G$. The adjacency matrix $A'$ of $G$ may be split into blocks
$$
A'=\pmatrix{
0 &A^T\\
A&0
},
$$

The propagation operator $M=A'/d$ is used for random walks on such a graph. It describes where you can get (and the probality) in **one** step, starting from a given vertex.

Now $M^2$ describes where you get with **two** steps and has the following form
$$
M^2=d^{-2}\pmatrix{
A^TA&0\\
0&AA^T
}.
$$

I think I may interpret $A^TA$ as the adjacency matrix of a $d^2$-regular, not necessarily simple graph,  $\phantom{(EDIT2:)}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!$ *since it will have $d$ self-loops for each vertex*, graph, so my question is:

> May I use $\phantom{(EDIT:)}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!$  *one of the blocks of* $M^2$ as propagation operator, when I restrict a given problem to walks of even length?

It feels to me that I'm loosing some information because the graph that $\phantom{(EDIT:)}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!$ *one of the blocks of* $M^2$ acts on has only half of the vertices of $G$. Is this related to a certain kind of symmetry adapted basis?

Comment: $M^2$ acts on all vertices of $G$ - even length walks stating on white vertices and even length walks starting on black vertices.

Comment: Why is $A^TA$ $d^2$-regular? Any number of the two-step paths may lead to the same vertices.

Comment: @joriki I tried some examples and was musing about the analogy between $d$-regular $\leftrightarrow A'/d$ and $d^2$-regular $\leftrightarrow (A')^2/d^2$. What do you want to tell me with *Any number of the two-step...* ? All in all the $d^2$-regularity is not the thing that I'd like to have the focus. The focus is on the blocks. Sorry if this is distracting...

Comment: Sorry, I'd missed what you meant by "not necessarily simple". In fact it will never be simple, since it will have $d$ self-loops for each vertex.

Comment: @joriki although *[the resulting graph] will never be simple*, do you think my problem has a *simple* solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because $M^2$ is block diagonal, so
$$
M^{2k}=(M^2)^k=d^{-2k}\pmatrix{
A^TA&0\\
0&AA^T
}^k
=
d^{-2k}\pmatrix{
(A^TA)^k&0\\
0&(AA^T)^k
}.
$$
To put it in a more combinatorial way, each even-length walk on $G$ consists of $2k$ steps, so it can be split into $k$ bisteps.  A bistep travels from one partite set of $G$ to the other and then back again, so ends up remaining within the same partite set.  The matrix $A^T A$ tells you how many ways to take a bistep from one vertex to another, within one of the partite sets, and $A A^T$ does the same for the other partite set.